# The user license doesn't allow the permission: Manage Surveys

Tags: survey, winter19, unlimited

Getting this error :

> Looks like you need a Survey Creator license before you can create this survey. Contact your Salesforce admin for help.

[image]

I already have a permission set called 'Survey Creator' with Read, Edit, Create, Delete on all Survey related objects after enabling the Survey.

[image]

Which user license allow us to Manage Surveys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to purchase license "Survey Creator license". You can create only one free survey. View more detail here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=concept_surveys_org_requirements.htm&type=5